# Parse date string with NSDateFormatter with month begins from 0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, date, nsdateformatter

I can't parse this date string: @"2002 0 20", where 0 is January (First month in year is 0, not 1). 
Can I use `NSDateFormatter` to parse this string?

Here http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Parsing_Dates_Times I've read that month should starts on 1.

**UPDATE**
I need this formatter because I have much data in this format (it is not my data).

I've not found any solution with `NSDateFormatter` without creating a subclass and overriding format methods.
I don't use `NSScan,` because it is a too complicated solution, but I think @Andy is right.

I use this code to parse the string:

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(out __autoreleasing id *)obj forString:(NSString *)string range:

(inout NSRange *)rangep error:(out NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    int year = 0;
    int month = -1;
    int day = -1;

    int coutRead = sscanf([string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "Date.UTC(%i, %i, %i)", &year, &month, &day);

    BOOL result = NO;
    if (coutRead == 3)
    {
        NSDateComponents* components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        components.year = year;
        components.month = month + 1;
        components.day = day;

        *obj = [self.calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        result = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        obj = 0;
        *rangep = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
        result = NO;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do your date strings use `0` for January? Use `1` for January and things will be a lot easier for you.

Comment: Date formatter assumes that 1 is January

Comment: Can you explain why you have strings using this scheme? There might be a way to avoid the problem.

Comment: You used to be able to create a custom calendar that could probably be used to fake this, but that functionality appears to have been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
formatter.shortMonthSymbols = @[@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11"];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy MMM dd";  // Note 3 Ms for "short month" format
NSDate* theDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2002 0 20"];
```

Result:

```
2002-01-20 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set date format to short for that to work.

Comment: @Andy - You're welcome to update your answer with the complete code if you wish.

Comment: I just lost my 15 points, is that's what I get for fixing competitor's code ha? Life is unfair! *kidding*

Comment: @Andy -- Actually, I meant for you to update your own answer.

Comment: @HotLicks whatever man, who cares about scores. I was just kidding. :-) Don't worry, I'll reap my yield from updating your question hahaha! :-)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Parse manually.

At your disposal:

1. You have `NSString` that can split string on substrings array using custom delimiter, white space in your case. For example:

   ```
   -(NSArray*)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
   ```
2. `NSScanner` that you can use to read integers directly from string.

Documentation is straightforward and comprehensive.

Comment: That may be true. However, it would helpful to also include some suggestions on how they might parse the string. As written, this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Learn to read, q was "Can I use NSDateFormatter to parse this string?". The answer is no. Learn how to ask the right question.